# sort sublists by matching elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like below:

```
lst1 = [[5, 0], [5, 3], [6, 2], [6, 1], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 3], [7, 2], [7, 1], [7, 3], [0, 3], [2, 1], [3, 8]]
```

I want to create a list like below:

```
lst2 = [[5, 0, 3, 8], [6, 2, 1], [4, 0, 3, 8], [7, 2, 1], [5, 3, 8]]
```

`[5, 0, 3, 8]` is created from `[5, 0]`, `[0, 3]`, and `[3, 8]` because the last item of `[5, 0]` matched with the first item of `[0, 3]` and the last item of `[0, 3]` matched with the first element of `[3, 8]`. Similarly, `[6, 2, 1]` is from `[6, 2]` and `[2, 1]` and so on. The problem is how can I iterate `lst1` and create `lst2`? I know how to iterate list/list of lists, extract items, etc. but the difficulty I have here is by iterating `lst1` once how can I create `lst2`.

Comment: It looks like you want to remove elements that participate in solutions as you go, as you don't seem to want [5, 3, 8] from [5, 3] and [3, 8], correct? Also, are there duplicate elements in `lst1`? Or are all pairs in `lst1` unique?

Comment: I don't want to remove elements. Just mentioned few of them for instance (now updated). It should happen among all the pairs in `lst1`. All pairs in `lst1` are unique.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have only one match for the last item. For example, given `[5, 0]` do you know there is only one item starting with `0` if not what should you do?

Comment: No, there could be more than item starting with 0. For instance, if `lst1 = [[5, 0], [0, 3], [0, 4]]`, then `lst2=[[5, 0, 3], [5, 0, 4]]`.

Comment: So you're looking for all maximal paths in the directed graph whose edges are given by the input? There could be exponentially many of those. What are you planning to do with this output?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there will be no cycles? For example, `[1, 2]`, `[2, 3]`, and `[3, 1]` would form a cycle.

Comment: @user2357112, I think order matters. I asked in my answer but haven't heard back. If so, then the cycle would never close.

Comment: Why is `[4, 3, 8]` not in the output? Can you give a complete, precise specification of the operation you want to perform?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can iterate over the top loop "once," but it's not really "once," in that each iteration waltzes over its sublist. O(n^2), if I'm not mistaken:

```py
lst1 = [[5, 0], [5, 3], [6, 2], [6, 1], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 3], [7, 2], [7, 1], [7, 3], [0, 3], [2, 1], [3, 8]]


def accept(root, pair):
    if root[-1] == pair[0]:
        root.append(pair[1])


def longest_for_root(root, pairs):
    for i, pair in enumerate(pairs):
        accept(root, pairs[i])


def strings_for_list(pairs):
    for i, pair in enumerate(pairs):
        if i < len(pairs) - 1:
            lfr = pairs[i].copy()
            longest_for_root(lfr, pairs[i + 1:])
            if len(lfr) > 2:
                yield lfr

[*strings_for_list(lst1)]

# [[5, 0, 3, 8], [5, 3, 8], [6, 2, 1], [4, 0, 3, 8], [4, 3, 8], [7, 2, 1], [7, 3, 8], [0, 3, 8]]
```

Another option that presents itself is to put the entries in a `dict`, keyed by their initial and terminal digits, but I think that just changes what `accept()` looks like.

I presumed that you're looking for matches "in order," by which we mean that `[[5,0],[0,3]]` produces `[5, 0, 3]`, but `[[0,3],[5,0]]` produces nothing.